# How to know the boot time (kernel + init) in Alpine using openRC?

Tags: kernel, init, alpine-linux, openrc

I made a bit of research on the matter and also asked ChatGPT, but there doesn't seem to be a way to measure full boot time of an alpine distribution with OpenRC.

Using `dmesg`, I can see the last message `[    0.689037] Run /sbin/init as init process`

But I want to know how much time it took to "complete" the init process. My use case is boot time sensitive, that's why I'm asking.

Note I was able to boot an ubuntu 22.04 with systemd in 1s including kernel boot. In systemd, `systemd-analyze` is very useful. So I hope there is an equivalent (or a way) in openRC.

Comment: you can completely forget asking ChatGPT. ChatGPT doesn't understand *anything*. It's not programmed to! It is designed to give an answer that *sounds* right, but that never helps with technical problems that nobody else had previously. So, "I asked chatgpt" can never be your whole research. So, what else have you researched?

Comment: lol, documentation, issues, google and many blogs

Comment: bit surprised by that, because you could simply install a service that gets booted last and logs to dmesg / syslog

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller that's an answer. I'm fairly new to OpenRC, so that's very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install coreutils in order to get millisecond precision in alpine.

```
apk add coreutils
```

Then, we will create two services:

In /etc/init.d/boot-start

```
#!/sbin/openrc-run

description="Boot Start Service"

start() {
    ebegin "Starting boot-start"
    date +%s%3N > /var/boot-time.log
    eend $?
}
```

And in /etc/init.d/boot-end

```
#!/sbin/openrc-run

description="Boot End Service"

depend() {
        after *
}

start() {
        ebegin "Starting boot-end"
        boot_start_time=$(cat /var/boot-time.log)
        boot_end_time=$(date +%s%3N)
        duration=$((boot_start_time - boot_end_time))
        echo "Boot started at: $boot_start_time" > /var/boot-time.log
        echo "Boot ended at: $boot_end_time" >> /var/boot-time.log
        echo "Total duration: $duration milliseconds" >> /var/boot-time.log
        eend $?
}
```

And then we'll start the first at boot and the second last

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/boot-start
rc-update add boot-start boot
chmod +x /etc/init.d/boot-end
rc-update add boot-end default
```

The result will look like this

```
Boot started at: 1686811355808
Boot ended at: 1686811357194
Total duration: -1386 milliseconds
```

Comment: That's much nicer than anything I would have come up with! Big kudos to you!

Comment: I have to admit ChatGPT wrote much of the code. Except I had to debug the millisecond precision myself and install coreutils

Comment: when you know what to achieve, guiding ChatGPT can be very powerful. It's a good assistant :)

Comment: well you did ask ChatGPT for something it's been designed to do – produce text that looks right (in this case, to a shell interpreter) following a prompt, and my guess is all the bits and pieces for this were around already.

Comment: there's a few minor bugs; like, hm, your duration is negative ;)

Comment: Unfortunately stackexchange is not compatible with chatpgt. Because it can propose answers with high rate of incorrectness. 
The purpose of the site is to share answers proven by the experience of those who answer. 
Instead of giving negative duration or heavy installs, would a KISS answer have been enough?
For example, would displaying the date in a readable format suffice: `journalctl -kg` or `dmsg-T` ? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421832/2672544